# MySQL error : sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

i have this script where i'm used to do a simple projection for a dynamic result

```
    SELECT 
    M.nom_utilisateur, 
    SUM(M.montant_bulletin ) as Montant_Total_BS,
    SUM(M.montant_payer   ) as Montant_Total_payer,
    COUNT(M.ref_bs ) as nbr_bs_total,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mutuelle_bi.`Mutuelle` WHERE nom_utilisateur = M.nom_utilisateur  AND (M.nom_assurence  = "Star" AND M.etat_bs = "Remboursé")) as nbr_bs_total_payer,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mutuelle_bi.`Mutuelle` WHERE nom_utilisateur = M.nom_utilisateur  AND (M.nom_assurence  = "Star" AND M.etat_bs = "Non remboursé")) as nbr_bs_non_payer,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mutuelle_bi.`Mutuelle` WHERE nom_utilisateur = M.nom_utilisateur  AND (M.nom_assurence  = "Star" AND M.etat_bs = "En cours")) as nbr_bs_en_cours,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mutuelle_bi.`Mutuelle` WHERE nom_utilisateur = M.nom_utilisateur  AND (M.nom_assurence  = "Star" AND M.etat_bs = "Nouveau")) as nbr_bs_nouveau
    FROM mutuelle_bi.`Mutuelle` M
    WHERE M.nom_assurence  = "Star"
    GROUP BY M.nom_utilisateur
```

but something goes wrong ; as i have this error :

> 1055 - Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'mutuelle_bi.M.etat_bs' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

[image]

How may i modify my script by the way to solve this problem , 
**given that i shouldn't modify any config file  of my sql server** . and i should only write scripts

Any Suggestions ??

Comment: You have to use conditional counting instead of subqueries.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear whether you wan to keep `only_full_group_by`, which can be changed only for current session but is of course a feature to help prevent bogus result sets.

Comment: You can simple use the `ANY_VALUE()` function in the nonaggregated column. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40578865/439171

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT M.nom_utilisateur, 
       SUM(M.montant_bulletin ) as Montant_Total_BS,
       SUM(M.montant_payer) as Montant_Total_payer,
       SUM(M.etat_bs = 'Remboursé') as nbr_bs_total_payer,
       SUM(M.etat_bs = 'Non remboursé') as nbr_bs_non_payer,
       SUM(M.etat_bs = 'En cours') as nbr_bs_en_cours,
       SUM(M.etat_bs = 'Nouveau') as nbr_bs_nouveau
FROM mutuelle_bi.`Mutuelle` M
WHERE M.nom_assurence = 'Star'
GROUP BY M.nom_utilisateur;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also try to disable the `only_full_group_by` setting:

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Worked for me.